# Python3: Socks5 Support with Selenium Gecko-Driver not possible?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver, browser-automation

im using the chromedriver successfull, but id like to use the geckodriver now. If i use the method of inserting socks5 through the arguments it wont work on gecko/firefox.

The same code does run with chrome...Any  idea how to get socks5 running on geckodriver?

Thanks!

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options


def test(login):
    userProfile = r"c:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\inpo8iou.default"
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:9955')
    geckodriver = "./geckodriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=geckodriver)
    driver.get("https://whoer.net")


with open("accounts.txt", "r") as read_accounts:
    accounts = read_accounts.read().splitlines()
for account in accounts:
    login = account.split(":")
    test(login)
```

Answer (score 0):

For a Firefox socks5 proxy, these are the options you want (based on your example):

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
options.set_preference("network.proxy.socks", "127.0.0.1")
options.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_port", 9955)
options.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_version", 5)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try doing it in the following way

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType

prox = Proxy()
prox.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL
prox.http_proxy = "ip_addr:port"
prox.socks_proxy = "ip_addr:port"

capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
prox.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capabilities)# change to gecko/firefox here
```